# Stray "-->" appearing on page before load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I just moved my wordpress site from localhost to the live site, and it is showing "-->" before the page is loaded. What's that about?

Not sure if this is related, but the jquery scripts I am using have also stopped working.

[Link to the site here.](http://web.kangabell.com)

*Background:* I had a difficult time moving the site. At the last minute, before moving the site, I changed the theme folder name. This broke a lot of instances throughout the theme where it referred to a path through that folder, so I had to fix those. I used a [search and replace tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) on the DB, but there were also some instances in the CSS I found that had to be fixed manually. Also, when I tried to import the SQL DB into the live site via PHP myAdmin, it said there was a syntax error. That seemed over my head, so I tried to just import the WP content through their import tool and then manually set up the menus and such again.

Comment: That sounds like a missing comment opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "unopened" comment block. Without the opening `<!--`, the stray closing `-->` is printed on the page.

If you are using a CMS (yep, you tagged WordPress), then

1. You'd have to find that line where the `-->` appears.
2. Look at the surrounding code and determine what it is. It could be a part of

   - The template
   - A plugin
   - User content (especially unfiltered input)
   - WordPress itself (who knows, it might have slipped QA)
   - Something that you placed in your site that we don't know!
3. Look for that template/plugin/whatever and dig in!

Still, it's manual work, but at least you have a much narrower scope.

Comment: Any advice on how to find the offender, aside from manually sifting through every file?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, I think using the SO search tool for files content is way faster. You won't find that many `-->` in both HTML and PHP files.

Comment: Found it! It was in the header.php of my theme. Thanks, everyone. The javascript still isn't working, but that'll be another question : )

Comment: @Jueecy.new CMSes tend to generate *a lot* of dynamic content. The surrounding code might be dynamically generated, that it's not part of any static file at all. It's best to have a bit of context rather than a general search.